# Holomorphic form on Hyperilliptic Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to check that if we have an Hyperilliptic Rieamnn surface $X$ defined by $y^2=h(x)$, then $\frac{dx}{y}$ is a holomorphic $1$-form on $X$ if $g\geq 1$. I think i was able to do this for two of the chart because if we have $X$ we have $2$ smooth affine plane curves $X_1$ and $X_2$ associated to it, i think that in $X_1$ that is given by $y^2=h(x)$, $F(x,y):=y^2-h(x)$, we will have the local representations $\frac{dx}{f(x)}$ where $f(x)$ is a function do the implicit function theorem and $\frac{dy}{\partial F / \partial x}$ and they will both be holomorphic due to the conditions of the charts we are in, with this said i am having some difficulty with the local representation in the other charts and where to use the fact that $g\geq 1$ will be relevant to prove that this is holomorphic, so any help is aprecciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $g\geq 1$ for the affine plane curve $X_2$ defined by $w = z^{2g+2}h(1/z).$ Specifically, we have to worry about the points $\{(0,w)\in X_2\}$ because you already checked $dx/y$ defines a holomorphic 1-form in the neighborhood of points $\{(z\neq 0,w)\in X_2\}$ since they are glued with points of $X_1$. Under the isomorphism $(x,y)\mapsto (z,w) = (1/x,y/x^{g+1})$, $dx/y$ transforms to $(-z^{g-1}/w)dz$. If $g=0$, then this becomes $-dz/(zw)$, which you can check will not be holomorphic at $z=0$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, just one thing, When you talk about that isomorphism that glues the surfaces, isnt that only defined when $z \neq 0$? So that local representation wouldnt work for $z=0$,because we are using that glueing map?@erdoswiles

Comment: @Something I think I have seen this exercise in Miranda, in which he follows the convention of specifying the 1-form in only one chart and leaves to the reader that it works in other charts -- the only reasonable way to interpret what a form defined for $X_1$ will be for $X_2$ is using the isomorphism, I think. But strictly speaking, yes I think the form for $X_2$ should also be specified.

Comment: Yes this is an exercise in Miranda's book, yes i agree that it would be using the isomorphism and to use the transitions maps to check what the form as to give, but sometimes its a bit confusing cause we are not always working on the full domain of the charts, maybe we have "expand" from what we get to the full the chart, and notice that it couldnt be done in a way to be holomorphic.